# Why this .yml file doesn't get loaded properly?

Tags: playframework, yaml

I've been trying to load the following .yml file using the following code, and it just don't seem to work.

How I'm loading it:

```
@Test
public void testLoadData() {
    Fixtures.loadModels("initial-data.yml");
    Assert.assertTrue("Item2.count() should be greater than zero",Item2.count() > 0);
}
```

initial-data.yml

```
# Test data
Item2(firstItem2):
    item2: test
```

Item2 .class

```
@Entity
public class Item2 extends Model {

    public String item2;

    public Item2(String item2) {
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

}
```

Again, this is a very simple stuff, at least I thought you would be simple... Just don't know why I'm getting an AssertionFailedError. The yml file is properly encoded, I've typed it myself. Also, I've tested the [tutorial's files](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/yaml) and they've worked just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your initial-data.yml located in the test directory (not conf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this content for 'initial-data.yml'

```
Foo(firstItem2):
   item2: test
```

If you don't get an error a wrong 'initial-data.yml' is used.

Comment: Yes... I had another file called initial-data.yml in `apps`... And while running the class in the `test` source folder, play looked for it in `apps` first. Thanks for the tip. I will watch out for that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try a

```
Fixtures.loadModels("initial-data.yml");
JPA.em().flush();
Assert.assertTrue("Item2.count() should be greater than zero",Item2.count() > 0);
```

Does this help?

Comment: No, it doesn't =\ Thanks. I will create another project later and try to load the models in that project.